# Install4j Unix GUI installer activates the uninstaller failure screen although no failures have occured during uninstall

Tags: install4j

I'm using an install4j Unix GUI uninstaller in console mode to uninstall a service (daemon).

The uninstaller seems to perform the uninstallation successfully without showing any errors, but for some reason it activates the UninstallFailureScreen, bypassing my actions in the success screen:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.LoadResponseFileAction [ID 20]: Execute action
       ...
       Execute action successful after 17 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RequestPrivilegesAction [ID 83]: Execute action
       ...
       Execute action successful after 0 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.StartupScreen [ID 14]: command: move 1 screens, executing actions, checking condition
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallWelcomeScreen [ID 15]: Show screen
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallWelcomeScreen [ID 15]: command: move 1 screens, executing actions, checking condition
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallationScreen [ID 16]: Show screen
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.services.StopServiceAction [ID 82]: Execute action
       ...
       Execute action successful after 695 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.text.ReadTextFromFileAction [ID 689]: Execute action
       ...
       Execute action successful after 1 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.RunScriptAction [ID 1147]: Execute action
       ...
       Execute action successful after 3 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.RunScriptAction [ID 1040]: Execute action
       ...
       Execute action successful after 56 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.UninstallFilesAction [ID 17]: Execute action
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.services.InstallServiceAction: executing auto uninstall
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.desktop.RegisterAddRemoveAction: executing auto uninstall
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.fileinst.FileRemover: postponing deletion of /opt/***/.install4j/user.jar
       postponing deletion of /opt/***/.install4j/i4jruntime.jar
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.UninstallFilesAction [ID 17]: Execute action successful after 119 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallationScreen [ID 16]: command: move 1 screens, executing actions, checking condition
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallFailureScreen [ID 19]: Show screen
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.RunScriptAction [ID 1158]: Execute action
       ...
       Execute action successful after 2 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallFailureScreen [ID 19]: command: finish
       cleaning up
       Finished
```

Can anyone see what went wrong?

I'm using install4j 5.1.14, the OS is CentOS 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.fileinst.FileRemover: postponing deletion of    /opt/***/.install4j/user.jar
postponing deletion of /opt/***/.install4j/i4jruntime.jar
```

triggers the "Uninstallation failure" screen.

You can simply delete the screen or deselect its "Quit after screen" property.

Comment: I think that this output is generated by the "Uninstall files" action, so there's no escaping it in the uninstaller. Moreover, it says that it postpones the deletion of an install4j jar, not a file belonging to my application. How can I workaround this failure?

Comment: The "Uninstall files" action does not display a screen. The "Uninstall failure" screen is a separate entity and can be removed from the uninstaller.

Comment: That seems very hackish. I want the uninstall failure screen to appear in case of an actual uninstall failure. I just don't want the uninstaller to fail due to the postponed removal of a file I don't control.

Comment: This is actually the only case in which the "Uninstall failure" screen is shown, so you might as well remove it.

Comment: That's strange. I was my understanding that the uninstaller shows the failure screen if one of its actions fails. For instance, a file deletion or the un-installation of a service. In such a case, I would like to show a relevant failure screen.

Comment: No, each action has its own "Error message" property. If set, it is displayed immediately.